# How to improve this text highlighting?

Tags: highlighting, typewriter, soul, letterspacing

I want to highlight some letters which represent an amino acid sequence of a protein using different colors.
The below code works fine, but the highlighted box is not fitting exactly the letters, as you can see in the MWE output it is slightly shifted toward the bottom of letters and not centered, so how to justify this to make it in the center of letters?

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\definecolor{set1}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\definecolor{set2}{RGB}{102,255,102}
\usepackage{soul} % for highlighting  
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Inconsolata} % monospace font 
\newenvironment{protseq}{\myfont}{\par} 

\begin{document}
\begin{protseq}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\hlc[set2]{MLGSRAVMLL LLLPWTAQG}R AVPGGSSPAW TQCQQLSQ\hlc[set1]{K}L CTLAWSAHPL & 50\\
VGHMDLREEG DEETTNDVPH IQCGDGCDPQ GLRDNSQFCL QRIHQGLIFY & 100\\
E\hlc[set1]{K}LLGSDIFT GEPSLLPDSP VGQLHASLLG LSQLLQPEGH HWETQQIPSL &    150\\
SPSQPWQRLL LRF\hlc[set1]{K}ILRSLQ AFVAVAARVF AHGAATLSP & 189\\
\end{tabular}
\end{protseq}
\end{document}
```

**MWE Output**

[image]

**Update**
Using Stephan Lehmke's answer, problem was solved even when using `Inconsolata` font plus alignment is preserved, just amazing!

[image]

Comment: For letters with descenders (like `Q`) the box fits. Making it "jump" depending on letter form would not look that good either.

Comment: Do you suggest another monospace font without descenders, if any?

Comment: @doctorate, just for caps?

Comment: @ChrisH yes just for caps.

Comment: @doctorate, I had an idea but I was proved wrong - it's a pity http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html uses "the quick..." rather than "The Quick" as Q is the only capital with a descender in most fonts.

Comment: Nothing in [Fonts for Displaying Program Code in LaTeX](nepsweb.co.uk/docs/progfonts.pdf) by Adrian P. Robson
meets your requirement unfortunately

Comment: @ChrisH but, surely there must be a monospace font that has the *shortest* descender for `Q` among other fonts, any idea?

Comment: @doctorate form the PDF I linked, it looks like Bera Mono/ Deja Vu Sans Mono wins, or if you want typewriter-style serifs TXTT - instructions for use are in the PDF  I linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, `soul` doesn't offer much with respect to adjusting the position of the "highlighting blob".

By adding this to your preamble you can adjust the vertical position:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newdimen\hladdbelow
\newdimen\hladdabove

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\SOUL@hlpreamble
{%
  \advance\SOUL@uldp\hladdbelow
  \advance\SOUL@ulht\hladdabove
}{}{}
\makeatother

\hladdbelow-2pt
%\hladdabove1pt
```

**Explanation:** The three `soul` commands `\ul`, `\st` and `\hl` basically use the same code, only choosing different values for the dimensions `\SOUL@uldp` (depth of "highlighting block") and `\SOUL@ulht` (height of "highlighting block").

`\SOUL@hlpreamble` (used by `\hl`) determines these values "intelligently" based on the font size, but offers no interface for adjustment. So I'm introducing new dimensions `\hladdabove` (length to add on top) and `\hladdbelow` (length to add to bottom) which are added after the original determination.

As it is, it seems to be enough to take away a bit at the bottom (hence, `\hladdbelow-2pt`) but you can experiment with the values if you want a different adjustment.

---

The setting shown here produces (using `cmtt` font):

[image]

Comment: that solved it radically (updated output shows `Inconsolata` font when used). Can you pls explain the concept/code behind your answer a little bit?

Comment: @doctorate edited

Answer (score 2):

You can use just `\colorbox` instead of `\hl`, assuming that the highlihted sequence does not wrap at the end of lines:

```
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\fboxsep1pt\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
```

[image]

I don't have `Inconsolata` font, hence I changed.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%
%\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\definecolor{set1}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\definecolor{set2}{RGB}{102,255,102}
\usepackage{soul} % for highlighting
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\fboxsep1pt\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
%\newfontfamily\myfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Inconsolata} % monospace font
\newenvironment{protseq}{\ttfamily}{\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{protseq}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\hlc[set2]{MLGSRAVMLL LLLPWTAQG}R AVPGGSSPAW TQCQQLSQ\hlc[set1]{K}L CTLAWSAHPL & 50\\
VGHMDLREEG DEETTNDVPH IQCGDGCDPQ GLRDNSQFCL QRIHQGLIFY & 100\\
E\hlc[set1]{K}LLGSDIFT GEPSLLPDSP VGQLHASLLG \hlc[set2]{LSQLLQPEGH HWETQQIPSL &    150\\
SPSQPWQRLL LRF\hlc[set1]{K}ILRSLQ AFVAVAARVF AHGAATLSP & 189\\
\end{tabular}
\end{protseq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one problem, there is a subtle frameshift in your output, which I could replicate using the `Inconsolata` font, so not related to font type I guess, pls compare alignment of your output with that of the MWE output.

Comment: @doctorate Frameshift? May be it is `\fboxsep`? Also a `\vphantom{Q}` looks better in the definition. I just wanted to convey the idea through the answer and it is not fully perfect, I admit :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the macro `\hl{}` includes a `\strut` to adjust the box depth, so that it has the same depth when it contains characters with descenders (such as `Q`) and when it does not. This guarantees the height of the box to be consistent.

However, perhaps for the chosen font, the depth appears to be a bit too large.

You can have a finer control of the result if you use tikz (which admittedly is overkill for this problem). Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\definecolor{set1}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\definecolor{set2}{RGB}{102,255,102}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Inconsolata} % monospace font
\newenvironment{protseq}{\myfont}{\par}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\tikz[baseline=(T.base)]
   \node[inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=0pt, fill=#1](T){\vphantom{Q}#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{protseq}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\hlc[set2]{MLGSRAVMLL LLLPWTAQG}R AVPGGSSPAW TQCQQLSQ\hlc[set1]{K}L CTLAWSAHPL & 50\\
VGHMDLREEG DEETTNDVPH IQCGDGCDPQ GLRDNSQFCL QRIHQGLIFY & 100\\
E\hlc[set1]{K}LLGSDIFT GEPSLLPDSP VGQLHASLLG LSQLLQPEGH HWETQQIPSL &    150\\
SPSQPWQRLL LRF\hlc[set1]{K}ILRSLQ AFVAVAARVF AHGAATLSP & 189\\
\end{tabular}
\end{protseq}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I used `\vphantom{Q}` to achieve the same goal than with `\strut`, but this solution produces a shorter box depth. You can also remove the `\vphantom{Q}`, so that the depth of the box fits exactly its contents, but this would produce different box depths for Q and K, which IMHO doesn't look good.

The advantage of using TikZ is that you can easily achieve other effects, such as rounded corners, irregular edges, etc.. For example:

```
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\tikz[baseline=(T.base)]
   \node[inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=0pt, fill=#1, rounded corners=2pt](T){\vphantom{Q}#2};}
```

produces:

[image: Result2]

and

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\tikz[baseline=(T.base)]
\node[inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=0pt, fill=#1, decorate,
   decoration={random steps, amplitude=1pt, segment length=0.5ex}](T){\vphantom{Q}#2};}
```

produces:

[image: Result3]

Which is ugly, but shows the possibilities :-)

## Update

Note that if you go too wild with the shape of the highlighting blob, the alignment with the surrouding text can be affected. This can be fixed by setting the bounding box of the tikz drawing exactly to the shape of the highlighted text, allowing the "blob" to spill out this bounding box.

The following example shows more clearly what I mean:

```
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\tikz[baseline=(TT.base)]{
   \node[inner sep=0pt](TT){\vphantom{Q}#2};  % rectangle with the text to highlight
   \useasboundingbox (TT.south west) rectangle (TT.north east);
   \node[inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=1pt, fit=(TT)] (T){}; % rectangle with the highlighting blob
   % now draw arbitrary shapes based on the last rectangle
   \fill[#1, opacity=0.5] (T.north west) to[out=5, in=185] (T.north east)
          -- (T.south east) to[out=190, in=10] (T.south west) -- cycle;
}}
```

Result:

[image: Result4]

Comment: pls note that out of the 3 outputs you kindly posted, the last one showed unsatisfactory alignment compared with the earlier two outputs.

Comment: @doctorate Good point! See my update